# MapStruct error with Nested Source and Nested Target Properties

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I am using `mapstruct` for converting Domain in DTO below is mapping is am using :-

```
   @Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {})
   public interface CategoriesMapper {
      @Mapping(source = "regionsid.id", target = "regionsid.id")
      CategoriesDTO categoriesToCategoriesDTO(Categories categories);  
   } 

    public class Categories implements Serializable {
        private Regions regionsid;
        public Regions getRegionsid() {
            return regionsid;
        }

        public void setRegionsid(Regions regions) {
            this.regionsid = regions;
        }

    }

    public class CategoriesDTO implements Serializable {
        private RegionsDTO regionsid;
        public RegionsDTO getRegionsid() {
            return regionsid;
        }

        public void setRegionsid(RegionsDTO regions) {
            this.regionsid = regions;
        }

    }

    public class Regions implements Serializable {
        private Long id;
    }

    public class RegionsDTO implements Serializable {
        private Long id;
    }
```

So i have some structure at both source and target side, but i am getting below error:-

```
CategoriesMapper.java:28: error: Unknown property "regionsid.id" in return type.
```

what if i have Set

Source -

```
private Set<Regions> regions = new HashSet<>();
```

Target -

```
private Set<RegionsDTO> regions = new HashSet<>();

CategoriesMapper.java:36: error: Can't map property "java.util.Set<com.equidity.xboard.service.dto.RegionsDTO> regions" to "java.util.Set<com.equidity.xboard.domain.Regions> regions". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.util.Set<com.equidity.xboard.domain.Regions> map(java.util.Set<com.equidity.xboard.service.dto.RegionsDTO> value)".`
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently MapStruct does not support automatic mapping of nested properties. In order for your mapping to work you will need to provide one more method to your `CategoriesMapper`:

```
RegionsDTO regionsToRegionsDTO(Regions Regions);
```

There is currently on open issue ([#60](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/60)) and a pending PR ([#937](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/pull/937)) that are looking to tackle this new feature.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this I believe is to write a RegionsMapper interface, something like the following:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {})
public interface RegionsMapper extends EntityMapper<RegionsDTO, Regions> {

    Set<Regions> map(Set<RegionsDTO> value);
}
```

Note that the above code is declaring the method that the error message is asking for.

In addition you will also need to tweak the @Mapper annotation (first line of code in the question) so that it uses this new mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {RegionsMapper})
```

This question is a little old, but I just ran into something very much like it using JHipster.